# Jenkins: Slave doesn't use provided SSH key from project configuration to authenticate for Git

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

I have a (Linux) Jenkins master with ssh keys configured as 'SSH username with private key' which are directely entered using the web interface. The key is used to authenticate for Git on Codebase and this works as expected on the master node.

Now to build .NET applications, I've created a Windows slave node which should also use this key to clone repo's from codebase but it appears that the slave doesn't use the key at all causing authentication to fail.

Under SCM I have the correct URL and Credentials and the key test seems to be ok (since it's the master testing it). When running my build project I get the following (censored) error:

```
Started by user XXX
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on Windows Build Server (Windows) in workspace C:\Jenkins\workspace\XXX
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url git@codebasehq.com:XXX # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@codebasehq.com:XXX
> git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
> git fetch --tags --progress git@codebasehq.com:XXX +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@codebasehq.com:XXX
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:825)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1092)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.multiplescms.MultiSCM.checkout(MultiSCM.java:143)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1276)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:560)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:485)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress git@codebasehq.com:XXX +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: XXX@codebasehq.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I assume I don't have to copy the key to the slave myself because that would render the key provider in Jenkins useless? Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

**ND**

EDIT:

Manually copying the private key from the Jenkins GUI into an `id_rsa` file on the slave node makes it possible to clone when directely working inside the VM but building with Jenkins still gives the same error. Still looking for an awnser.

Comment: Any luck? facing the same, with a few slaves working normally and others not